# ETHER did not reach Myetherwallet

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, etherscan, exchanges

```
I send ETHER from Livecoin ,Etherscan confirm transaction but Ether did reach Myetherwallet.
```

Livecoin and Etherscan shows that transaction successful.
What should Ido for recover my ether?

Comment: can you please provide the transaction id so that we can look into the issue that occurred?

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet is simply an interface. They do not have the ability to hold withdrawals, hold deposits, access your account, cancel transactions, or see anything besides what is publicly viewable on a blockchain explorer, like etherscan.io.

In order to resolve this, you should to contact the team or exchange corresponding to your transaction issue and explain the situation. They should be able to help you determine what is going on.